# Magento 1.9 Paypal Express Checkout force shipping address on review page for non logged in user

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, shipping-address

In the last weeks, Paypal Express is not always importing the address via on the review page and the customer is not able to select shipping methods for non logged in user. The customer just assumes everything is ok and clicks complete order and the order is placed.

However there is no shipping address or billing address in the order/invoice.

Is there a way to force shipping address from Paypal account to Magento? via Paypal API?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the RWD theme with significant customizations. My solution was to disable or delete

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/paypal.xml
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/paypal
```

allow only the

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/paypal
```

template and layout to handle this process.

**Replace rwd with [your-theme] if you are having this issue.**

In addition make sure there are no modifications in the

`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal` or overrides in `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal` (if applicable)

If you are still having issues after doing all the above, look to see if your site has been migrated from an older version (< magento 1.9).

- Go to Magentocommerce archive and download that version of Magento (if older than Magento 1.7 this solution may not work).
- Create a local version in `app/core/local/Mage/Paypal/` then copy the older version (archive) onto your site.
- Check to see if the address appears. If so you may not be able to checkout after changing shipping method disable the

  `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php` file.

I'd like to mention that there have been many unanswered questions about paypal express on stackexchange/google and it seems that paypal solved some of them in the Magento 1.9 version.

Some questions were closed out because developers were not able to duplicate issue or left unanswered. I am hoping that my solution might provide some help on where to focus and things to try.